# I can't use variable coming from outside Json in Json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

```
var dataid=45;
listStations.push(data[i].ID);
$.getJSON("https://example.com/json?id=" + data[i].ID, function (parkDetay) {
       var getCapacity = 100 - (Math.round((100 / parkDetay[0].capacity) * parkDetay[0].emptyCapacity));
       nowCapacity = getCapacity;
       console.log(dataid);
       nearStations.push([dataid, nowCapacity, nowValue])
   });
```

I give a constant value before the json parenthesis begins.

```
dataid = 45;
```

or a dynamic variable

```
dataid = data[i].ID;
```

Both of them do not print with console.log in JSON and return "0".

What to do? It does not push the series as an extra

Comment: There's nothing wrong with `dataid` in the snippet you posted. Verify the callback is actually invoked; it sounds like it's not per your statement "It does not push the series as an extra"

Comment: Adding elements to alert or console or array. The dataid value is 0 in all three.

Comment: There is no JSON in this question. JSON is a text format for storing and sending data. `parkDetay` is a JavaScript object that has been parsed from the JSON received from the request to example.com. So when you say "the json parenthesis begins" that doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Is this code in a loop? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example